# Architecting an account system for oauth that bridges a new and legacy system

Tags: authentication, legacy, oauth2

So this question is specific to implementing auth in our system but I'm looking for high-level (just the architecture) solution or advice on which direction to head towards.

**Overview (TL;DR)**

Our company is building a new product (Product P) and we want to unify authentication for its API with a recently re-written product (Product A) that uses a legacy database. Product A was re-written to use oAuth 2 for authentication and right now this **works great** but I'm having a difficult time visualizing how to bridge these two systems because of the requirements the legacy database imposes on what an "authenticated entity" can be in Product A.

**Product A**

- An **Authenticated Entity** is a **User** and authenticates using username/password.
- A **User** belongs to a **Company**.
- A **Company** can authenticate using an **api key** but internally the key is just associated with a dummy **User** that belongs to that **Company** with a certain set of permissions.
- Authentication is done with **Resource Owner Credential Grants**, either password grant (user/pass) or apikey grant.
- User and Company tables are stored in one database alongside the rest of Product A's data (IE not separate databases, can't easily refactor app to change this)

**Product B**

- **Authenticated Entity** has not been decided on yet
- Usage is not exclusive to users of **Product A** (IE it's an independent product) but,
- **Company**s from **Product A** will rely heavily on **Product B's** API for some core functionality
- The functionality is **contextual** based on the entity authenticating from **Product A**

**Basically these two products are offered independent of each other to customers BUT will depend on each other's APIs for some core functionality -- and the functionality is contextual based on who is authenticating.**

---

So the main questions I've been wrestling with:

- How do I unify these two systems under one **Authenticated Entity**?

  - This is more a question of "what should an AE look like?" rather than "how do I handle permissions?" because I know I can do that with scopes.
- Given that I have only one identifier (**name** from **oauth_client**) that I can determine from an access token, what should the identifying information be on the **Authenticated Entity** so I can determine whether it's a User from Product A, a Company from Product A, or an AE from Product B?
- Is there a way to architect **Authenticated Entity** on Product B that will make bridging Product A easier?

Comment: Will users have access to the actual API or to interfaces/views in their respective product that will make use of the alternate API to provide functionality?

Comment: Users of both products will have access to both actual APIs. As for Product B's APIs that Product A uses -- I would like to treat Product A's requests as if they were an independent user (IE they get no special treatment just because we use them internally)